# Edittext Keyboard Not Showing After First Input

Tags: android, android-edittext

So I need an input box for text in my android app.
I have this in my xml:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/inputCodePA"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="@string/inputHint"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/arrowRightPA"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/arrowRightPA">
    <requestFocus/>
</EditText>
```

and this:

```
public void setOnClickListners(){
    final EditText inputBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputCodePA);
    inputBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            inputBox.clearFocus();
            inputBox.requestFocus();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(inputBox, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
        }
    });
    inputBox.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            inputBox.setText("");
            inputBox.clearFocus();
            inputBox.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

For my code in my activity's class (setOnClickListner() is called in my onCreate()).

But, whenever after I type something into the EditText box and press Enter, I can not open the keyboard to enter text again.

I know I'm making a really basic error, but I can't seem to figure out what.
After all, this is the first time an EditText failed me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HA!

I found out the problem!

It was because I had a ScrollView below the EditText in the code (which made the ScrollView become 'in front'), which did not allow the user to click on the view at all!

Hope this helps other people who makes these stupid mistakes!